# Search all tables for a string and sort by number of occurrences of that string in a row (SQLite)

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, sql-order-by, union

Lets say there are 3 tables like this in my database.

```
table A         table B         table C
id|title|body   id|name |desc   id|user |comment
1 |xx   |xy     1 |zy   |yz     1 |zz   |yz
2 |xyz  |yy     2 |xx   |xx     2 |xx   |xy
3 |zy   |xx     3 |yy   |yy     3 |yyy  |yz
```

And when the search string is 'x' the result should be

```
|col1 |col2|
|xx   |xx  | -- from table B, because 4 occurrences
|xx   |xy  | -- from table A, because 3 occurrences
|xx   |xy  | -- from table C, because 3 occurrences
|zy   |xx  | -- from table A, because 2 occurrences
|xyz  |yy  | -- from table A, because 1 occurrence
```

Which query should I run in SQLite to get such a result?

EDIT: Changed column names in B and C to show they're not related.

Comment: If those titles and bodies are related, they should be in a single table and referenced.

Comment: They're not, I should probably change it to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `union all` to bring the matches from the three tables. Then, you want to order the results by the number of matching characters. One approach is to compare the length of the original strings to their length one the search character has been removed.

```
select title col1, body col2 from a where title like '%x%' or body like '%x%'
union all select name, descr from b where name like '%x%' or descr like '%x%'
union all select user, comment from c where user like '%x%' or comment like '%x%'
order by 
    length(col1) 
    + length(col2) 
    - length(replace(col1, 'x', '')) 
    - length(replace(col2, 'x', '')) desc
```